# Laravel 5.5 application not booting anymore with "A facade root has not been set."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

For some reason one of our applications isn't booting anymore. The stack trace looks like this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:218
Stack trace:
#0 /app/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(43): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('get', Array)
#1 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(352): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Dotenv\Exception\InvalidFileException))
#2 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(123): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(Dotenv\Exception\InvalidFileException))
#3 /app/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 {main}
  thrown in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 218
```

I'm sure there's something that changed and stopped the application from booting. But I have no clue what exactly happened. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you upgrade the app's laravel version recently?

Comment: No, the version didn't change.

Comment: Was there any custom Facade created recently for which `getFacadeAccessor` is not properly configured in facade class? maybe comment each custom facade one by one and then see which one is the culprit?

Comment: `Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php` will be the file where you can see if it can not instantiate the class using `getFacadeRoot`, it throws that error

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm not quite sure how I would find the culprit from within the `getFacadeRoot` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was quiet simple but difficult to find.

.env variables should not be assigned as KEY="VALUE" and also too many spaces can crash the initialisation of the .env

i.e: 
DB_HOST= mysql

Just correct the .env and it should work like a charme

Answer (score 1):

As a sanity check, completely delete your `vendor` directory and then re-install (or update) your dependencies. It is possible a file in there was mistakenly changed and is now causing problems.

```sh
rm -rf vendor
composer update
```